# Trouble grabbing text from input and textarea

Tags: jquery

```
function createMessage(copySponsor) {
            var values = [];
            var distid = <%= Session("DistributorID") %>;
            var subject = $('#diaSubject').text();
            var message = $('#diaMessage').text();

            $("#toList > option").each(function() {
                values.push($(this).val());
            });
            alert(values + '\n' + copySponsor + '\n' + subject + '\n' + message);
        }

<input id="diaSubject" class="diaWidth" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="255" />
<textarea id="diaMessage" class="diaWidth" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I want to grab what they type for the subject and what they type for the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use val()

```
var subject = $('#diaSubject').val();
var message = $('#diaMessage').val();
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that right after posting.  Could of swore it needed to be .text..  But .val worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var subject = $('#diaSubject').val();
var message = $('#diaMessage').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want .val();

html

```
<input id="diaSubject" class="diaWidth" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="255" />
<textarea id="diaMessage" class="diaWidth" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<input id="submit_button" type="submit">
```

js

```
function createMessage() {

            var subject = $('#diaSubject').val();
            var message = $('#diaMessage').val();

            alert(subject + '\n' + message);
        }

$('#submit_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    createMessage() ;

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7mUV6/